# How to get selected item data?

Tags: knockout.js

My background is mainly asp.net/c# and I´m new to Durandal/Knockout. I´m trying to build a view to show a list of objects and upon selection of one item, show the selected item´s data. My problem is that whatever item is selected the data returned is always the last item´s data.

Below are my view,

... Markup not shown

```
<div data-bind="visible: convenios().length > 0" style="height:30px">
Pesquisa retornou <span  data-bind="text: convenios().length"></span> conveniados.
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <section  class="grd-convenio" data-bind="foreach: convenios" style="width:25%; height:300px; overflow-y: scroll">
        <article>
        <div class="grd-convenio-detalhe"  title="Clique para alterar">
            <span class="grd-convenio-nome" data-bind="text: nome"></span>
            <span class="grd-convenio-id" data-bind="text: id"></span><br/>
            <span class="grd-convenio-cidade" data-bind="text: cidade"></span>
            <span class="grd-convenio-ativo" data-bind="text: servicosativos"></span>
        </div>
        </article>        

    </section>
</div>
```

and part of my viewmodel:

```
var convenio = function (id, nome, cidade, cnpjcpf, servicosativos) {

    self = this;

    self.idformatado = ko.observable("[" + id + "]");
    self.id = ko.observable(id);
    self.nome = ko.observable(nome);
    self.cidade = ko.observable(cidade);
    self.cnpjcpf = ko.observable(cnpjcpf);
    self.servicosativos = ko.observable(servicosativos);
    self.estiloativo = ko.computed(function () {
        if (self.servicosativos() > 0)
            return 'grd-convenio-detalhe-ativo';
        else
            return 'grd-convenio-detalhe-inativo';
    });
    self.convenioselecionado = ko.observable("");
    return self;

};

var convenios = ko.observableArray([]);
var tamanho = ko.observable("0");
var convenioselecionado = ko.observable("");
var pesquisacodigo = ko.observable("");
var pesquisanome = ko.observable("");
var pesquisacidade = ko.observable("");

var filtrar = function () {

 ... Retrieve data from Database and pushes data into convenios observablearray
            $.each(resultado.pesquisa.retorno, function (i, item) {
                convenios.push(new convenio(item.idconveniado, item.nome, item.cidade, item.cnpjcpf, item.servicosativos));
            });


};

alterarCadastro = function (selecionado) {
    if (selecionado && selecionado.id()) {
        alert(selecionado.nome());
    }
};


var viewAttached = function(view) {
    bindEventToList(view, '.grd-convenio-detalhe', alterarCadastro);
};

var bindEventToList = function (rootSelector, selector, callback, eventName) {
    var eName = eventName || 'click';
    $(rootSelector).on(eName, selector, function () {
        var selecionado = ko.dataFor(this);
        callback(selecionado);
        return false;
    });
};


return {
    convenios: convenios,
    filtrar: filtrar,
    tamanho: tamanho,
    pesquisacodigo: pesquisacodigo,
    pesquisanome: pesquisanome,
    pesquisacidade: pesquisacidade,
    alterarCadastro: alterarCadastro,
    displayName: 'Convênio',
    viewAttached: viewAttached

}
```

});});

The view is shown as expected but when I select any item the data (ko.datafor) returned in the bindEventTolist function is always the last item´s data. What am I doing wrong? Is this a good approach to this kind of app? TIA.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the last item's data is returned'?  Your alert is set to show whatever is clicked but it is not going to do anything with that data.

Comment: @kadumel this is the problem. The alert always show the property "nome" of the **last** item, and not the property "nome" of the actual clicked item. I need to get the id of the clicked item to show its data , but since I always get last item´s data I´m not doing anything yet. I´m just showing an alert of the returned "nome".

Comment: It is a bit difficult to follow the code because of the language difference, but for all intents and purposes your alert() should be showing the current object.  Could you create a fiddle re-producing this issue so we can see what is going on in the background?

Comment: Sorry @kadumel. I could not make the fiddle work although the js code is ok. You know, I'm new to all these tools. But if you want to have a look at the  [fiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/zenute/yQgAm/4/). I believe it will help you understand. Any item I click, alert always return 'name4'.

Comment: @kadumel , I made a minor change in the fiddle [new fiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/zenute/yQgAm/6/)

Comment: I have marked up your fiddle and given an answer that should help.  Let me know if you have any other questions and please mark the answer as correct if it is indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/yQgAm/8/

I have updated your fiddle, but it took quite some time : )

You were making it more difficult than it needs to be so I am trying to put some markup on your code to show what I changed, if I can remember it all.  One of the biggest things I went back and did was to rename your methods using camelCase to ensure no typos existed.  Next, I took the parter function out of your viewModel, as it is a class on it's own and doesn't need to be defined in there.

Then I gave your view model a scope with self = this.  This just lets the view model know that anything inside of it with a self. predecessor is defined as part of this scope.

Next, since I am no jsFiddle master and you were trying to use both jQuery ($.each) and KnockOut (ko.) I replaced the $.each with a KnockOut utility called ko.utils.arrayForEach() which basically is the same thing.

I suspect when you were doing a forEach loop with the $.each in your code you were setting the value as the value of selectedPartner and then when you did showSelectedPartner it was just displaying the last value that you had set in your forEach loop.

If you want to take some of your original code and re-use it the biggest thing that I would suggest to do is remove the dependency to so many libraries.  You are confusing yourself by (assumption) learning jQuery, Knockout, and Durandal all at the same time while trying to understand basic JavaScript.  Take it one step at a time or you are going to end up with a LOT of code that does things you aren't 100% sure why.

```
function partner(id, name) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(id);
    self.pName = ko.observable(name);
}

function viewmodel() {
   var self = this;
   self.initialdata = ko.observableArray([
       { id: 1, name: "name1" } ,
       { id: 2, name: "name2" } ,
       { id: 3, name: "name3" } ,
       { id: 4, name: "name4" } ,
   ]);

    self.partners = ko.observableArray();  
    self.selectedPartner = ko.observable();  

    self.loadData = function () {
        self.partners([]);
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.initialdata(), function (item) {
            self.partners.push(new partner(item.id, item.name));
        });
    };
    self.showSelectedPartner = function (selected) {
        alert(selected.pName());
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewmodel());
```

And your view

```
<section>
    <div>
        <button data-bind="click: loadData">Load Data</button>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="visible: partners().length > 0" >Query returned <span data-bind="text: partners().length"></span> records</div>
    <div>
        <section data-bind="foreach: partners" >
            <article>
                <div title="Click to Update" data-bind="click: $parent.showSelectedPartner"> <span data-bind="text: id"></span>  
 <span data-bind="text: pName"></span>
                </div>
            </article>
        </section>
    </div>
</section>
```

I put a click binding on your div because viewAttached is a Durandal method letting the router know that the view is finished attaching and it can do something.  The bindToEventList you created is just saying if anything with that class that you had named it is clicked fire that method.  That is all good to use and more efficient but if you are just learning KnockOut I recommend learning how bindings work first.

Comment: thank you so much. I really appreciated your tips and advices. With your jsFiddle I managed to fix and run my original code. I intend to develop apps in Durandal/Knockout in a near future and I need to learn it fast. I will do some more reading on the subject. Thank you @Kadumel.

Comment: I did understand the Durandal code and was comfortable with it. I just  don´t know which one should I use, click binding or Durandal event handler. By the way, what really fixed my original code was declaring initialData as an observable array. Thank you once more.

Comment: Cool of it answered your question you can accept the answer.  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a new view when the item is clicked, you can add a new item view route to durandal router with a splat, eg  router.mapNav('item/:id'), and then change your markup to include a link to the new route. Something like this:

```
<section  class="grd-convenio" data-bind="foreach: convenios" style="width:25%; height:300px; overflow-y: scroll">
        <article>
        <a class="grd-convenio-detalhe" title="Clique para alterar" data-bind="attr: {href: '#/item/' + $data.id}">
            <span class="grd-convenio-nome" data-bind="text: nome"></span>
            <span class="grd-convenio-id" data-bind="text: id"></span><br/>
            <span class="grd-convenio-cidade" data-bind="text: cidade"></span>
            <span class="grd-convenio-ativo" data-bind="text: servicosativos"></span>
        </a>
        </article>        

    </section>
```

I personally prefer this solution as it follows the single responsibility principle by handing of all item specific logic to the new route's viewmodel.

Comment: Thank you @jaq316. It could be a solution to create a view to handle the item, but what I am really trying to find is a way to get the object "convenio" bound to the element clicked. ko.dataFor(this); always returns the last "convenio" object in the collection and not the clicked one.